# Thymeleaf Spring security integration sec:authorize is not working

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf templating engine with Spring security. 
I am also using Thymeleaf Spring Security integration modules in order to use sec:authorize functionality but it does not work for some reason. I am not getting any error, but all code in html div blockes get executed no matter which role a user has.

For example, when I log in as an EMPLOYEE, I also see 'GO to leaders' and 'GO to systems' buttons but I don't want for an EMPLOYEE to see those buttons.

Here is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>security</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>security</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot security</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my security config file

```
package com.example.security.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    public SecurityConfig(AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler) {
        this.authenticationSuccessHandler = authenticationSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        User.UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser(users.username("john").password("john").roles("TEST", "EMPLOYEE"))
                .withUser(users.username("mary").password("mary").roles("EMPLOYEE", "MANAGER"))
                .withUser(users.username("susan").password("susan").roles("EMPLOYEE", "ADMIN"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
                .antMatchers("/leaders/**").hasRole("MANAGER")
                .antMatchers("/systems/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/showmyloginpage")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateuser")
                //.successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }
}
```

Here is my home page html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Welcome to the home page!</p>
    <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
    </form>
    <form th:action="@{/showuser}" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="Show data" />
    </form>

    <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_MANAGER')">
        <form th:action="@{/leaders}" method="get">
            <input type="submit" value="GO to leaders" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
        <form th:action="@{/systems}" method="get">
            <input type="submit" value="GO to systems" />
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What HTML does it generate? is the `sec` tag visible within the tag if you inspect it?

Comment: It generates all of the buttons for "john" user. When I inspect it, it also shows sec tag, but I know that should not be allowed. Maybe I got wrong versions in pom file?

Answer (score 6):

The following dependency should resolve the issue

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Also change your XML namespace from

```
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5"
```

to

```
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"
```

Comment: @DejanIlic , updated answer, I suspect it is to do with your XML namespace too

Comment: @Dejanllic, my previous projects also just have `xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/"` as the `xmlns` in case my answer doesn't help.

Comment: Does it still print in the HTML?

Comment: Yes, it does print.

Comment: `xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"` was key to me!

Answer (score 0):

Problem soloved, something in my Thymeleaf configuration was interfering.

```
    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5")
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();

        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template engine with Spring integration")
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf view resolver")
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return viewResolver;
    }
```